# Using QDial to change time of a simple python timer

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to create a small python app that prints in console a message every n seconds. I also use PyQt for creating an user interface. I want to change the time period between the messages using a QDial, but when I change the value of time variable on the sliderMoved method the time doesn't change.

```
import sys
from threading import Timer,Thread,Event
from datetime import datetime

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QDial
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

stopFlag = Event()
time = 2

class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, event):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.stopped = event

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(time):
            print('Message')


def startThread():
    stopFlag.clear()
    thread = MyThread(stopFlag)
    thread.start()

def start_clicked():
    print("Start clicked")
    startThread()

def stop_clicked():
    print("Stop clicked")   
    stopFlag.set()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.start_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.start_btn.setText("Start")
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(start_clicked)
        layout.addWidget(self.start_btn)

        self.stop_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.stop_btn.setText("Stop")
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(stop_clicked)
        layout.addWidget(self.stop_btn)

        self.dial = QDial()
        self.dial.setMinimum(1)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(2)
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderMoved)
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)

    def sliderMoved(self):
        print("Dial value = %i" % (self.dial.value()))
        time = self.dial.value()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use threading?

Comment: You are only setting a local variable time in `sliderMoved`. The `time` variable there has only the scope of the function and does not affect your global `time` variable.

Comment: Avoiding global state, you could give the `MyThread` a class member `time` and give the thread to the Widget changing `thread.time`.

Comment: > Is it necessary to use threading? 

If you want something running in the background of a qt app and not block the app, I'd say yes.

Comment: But for this simple task, maybe `QTimer` is more appropriate?

Comment: @MaxNoe If you are going to answer me please use `@username`, on the other hand my question goes in the sense that there are other tools to execute tasks every n seconds, such as a QTimer, without the need to complicate with the use of threading . For example, assuming that "time" is updated, there is still another problem: "wait()" is blocking, to give an extreme example: let's say time is worth "10000000", and then change it to "1", that change will apply only after executing "wait(10000000)" since that function does not allow to alter the waiting time,

Comment: @MaxNoe [cont.] however with a QTimer it is totally different. My question goes in the sense of the need for threads, if the "print (foo)" is just the replacement of a time-consuming task then if threading is necessary but if not then a QTimer would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions have their own scope in python:

```py
time = 5

def foo():
    time = 10 # only local, not changing the global time.
    print(time)

foo()  # prints 10
print(time) # prints 5
```

You should avoid global state as much as possible. Here I add methods
and a time attribute to your `MyThread` object and change the time value of this object to make it work.
I also moved the event into the class and added a stop method.

```py
import sys
from threading import Thread, Event
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QDial

START_TIME = time.time()


def elapsed():
    return round(time.time() - START_TIME, 1)


class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, time):
        super().__init__() # call __init__ of the baseclass
        self.time = time
        self.stopped = Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stopped.wait(self.time):
            print(elapsed(), 'Message')

    # Thread has a method start, here we add the clearing to the signal
    def start(self):
        print(elapsed(), 'Started')
        self.stopped.clear()
        super().start()

    # new method stop
    def stop(self):
        print(elapsed(), 'Stopped')
        self.stopped.set()


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.thread = MyThread(time=2)
        self.start_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.start_btn.setText("Start")
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.thread.start)
        layout.addWidget(self.start_btn)

        self.stop_btn = QPushButton(self)
        self.stop_btn.setText("Stop")
        self.stop_btn.clicked.connect(self.thread.stop)
        layout.addWidget(self.stop_btn)

        self.dial = QDial()
        self.dial.setMinimum(1)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(self.thread.time)
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.sliderMoved)
        layout.addWidget(self.dial)

    def sliderMoved(self):
        print(elapsed(), "Dial value = %i" % (self.dial.value()))
        self.thread.time = self.dial.value()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
screen = Window()
screen.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```